# ask util generate-lwa-tokens is no longer available?

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

I'm getting started on Alexa Skill MAnagement SMAPI, so I need to get a refresh token. In the documentation it is specified that 'ask util generate-lwa-tokens' should be used, but in the current version 2.0 of 'ask' this option is no longer available. Thus, I obtained access tokens using postman as described here:
https://gist.github.com/marcelobern/fe44cee1dd5ed624e03b690a447e47fd

But when running some example of smapi what I get is a server error. The example and the error:

```
 from ask_smapi_sdk import StandardSmapiClientBuilder
 smapi_client_builder = StandardSmapiClientBuilder(client_id='***', 
 client_secret='***',
 refresh_token='***')
 smapi_client = smapi_client_builder.client()
try:
    result = smapi_client.list_skills_for_vendor_v1(vendor_id='***', full_response=True)
    print("==========================================")
    print(result.headers)
    print(result.body)
    print("==========================================")
except Exception as e:
    print(e.body if hasattr(e, 'body') else e)
```

The error:

```
{'error_description': 'The server encountered an internal error trying to '
                      'fulfill the request',
 'error_type': 'ServerError'}`
```

Thank you,

Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command is now added in the ask-cli v2.1.0, you can check the changelog at

https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#210-2020-04-16

Answer (score 0):

Solved. You have to be sure to use a refresh token since access token will throw a server exception